# What is an underlying topological space?

Tags: general-topology

What is an underlying topological space?

I don't get the definition of this in my topology book.

I wonder what the definition of an underlying topological space is.

Comment: You’ll have to give more context: you haven’t given enough information for the question to be answered.

Answer (score 6):

If you're dealing with a topological {group, vector space, ring or any other algebraic structure}, referring to "the underlying topological space" usually means to look at the object *only* as a topological space.

You can find this with Lie groups, the real spaces $\,\Bbb R^n\,$,  general Hilbert or Banach spaces, etc.